# Check if user have the role x when he add a reaction and give him an other role

Tags: discord.py, bots

Im learning python and trying to do a discord bot. And my english is very bad but just see the problem :

````py
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = bot.get_channel(998251077579313285)
    role1 = '1003097724796817523'
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel.id:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == "" and str(r.id) in role1:
      Role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="✨┃VIP")
      await user.add_roles(Role)```

This is my code and its not working but i dont have error.
Can you help me guys ? Thx so much
````

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](/tour) Please see [ask] and [help/on-topic]. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] (what is `r`?). Check if the `if` conditions are correct. I guess you need to change the `!=` in the first `if` to `==`. If you don't get any errors, you haven't written the code properly. What do you want the bot to do? When do you want the bot to give the role? Check if the checks are right. Your code executes the second `if` only `if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel.id` because there's a `return` after it (`return` means 'execute the rest of the code' in this case).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the actual and intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not code like `if not a: quit; b()`, when you can simply do `if a: b()`

As not to completely spoonfeed here, here's a hint of how you could accomplish your goal:

```py
if [ x for x in member.roles if x.id == myRoleId ]:
   await member.add_roles(role)
```

Your question was a bit vague, so if this is not what you're looking for, please comment.

Comment: I fix that today but i have a new error and i just send you that. The new code is just different of this one i send you that (my english is very bad sorry)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def check(reaction, message):
        return botMessage.id == reaction.message.id and reaction.emoji == "" and >>> user <<< != bot
```

You never defined `user`, do you mean `ctx.author`?